# Remove padding from qt4 application

Tags: qt4

I'm looking forward to remove padding completly:

[image: webkit qt]

See that ugly space beetween a `qtwebkit element` and the window.

The layout is only a `vbox`, and inside it lives the `webkit view`,

I tried with:

```
vbox->setSpacing(0);
```

But no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spacing is a space between widgets in layout. You need to set contents margins with `setContentsMargins` method. Margins define space beetween container edge and layout content.